# WPF combination between grid and stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, stackpanel

I am currently trying to find/implement a WPF control, which is a combination of a `Grid` and a `StackPanel`. That means, I like to have two columns with several items. An item is another control (e.g. single `Label`, `TextBox` with label in a panel, ...).

If an item is collapsed, the empty space should be filled with the next item, means I have always as less space used in the control as possible (without gaps between the single items).

I attached two images how it should look like.

Initial:
[image: Initial]

Item4 is collapsed (notice the shift of following up items):
[image: One item collapsed]

Does anybody have an idea or experience how to do something like that?

Comment: I think your control should contain two stack panels, contained in a grid. The code inside the control can assign it's contents to one of the panels

Comment: Did you try using a grid with two stack panels it?

Comment: You can always make your own custom panel `MyPanel: Panel` and customize how children are located by overriding `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride`. It's fairly straightforward, give it a try. Collapsing is tricky, as you didn't provide any solution of how exactly it should looks like. By clicking? What if children is a `TextBox` or other focusable/editable control? How un-collapsing is done?

Comment: @RobinBennett, you miss the shifting part after something is collapsed for which you need to dial with attached properties of following up children, which means your composite layout won't be easy.

Comment: How about a WrapPanel, which would handle collapsing child controls, and then draw the two boxes over the top?

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Place two rectangles with transparent fill and black stroke over an itemscontrol. Make them ishittestvisible false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for all the different solutions. Finally I solved it with the suggestion from Sinatr. So I created my own panel and override the ArrangeOverride:

```
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        List<UIElement> visibleItems = new List<UIElement>();
        double xColumn1 = 0;
        double xColumn2 = (finalSize.Width / 2) + (WIDTH_COLUMN_SEPERATOR / 2);
        double y = 0;

        double columnWidth = (finalSize.Width - WIDTH_COLUMN_SEPERATOR) / 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < InternalChildren.Count; i++)
        {
            UIElement child = InternalChildren[i];
            if (child.Visibility != Visibility.Collapsed)
            {
                visibleItems.Add(child);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < visibleItems.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i >= (visibleItems.Count - 1))
            {
                visibleItems[i].Arrange(new Rect(xColumn1, y, columnWidth, visibleItems[i].DesiredSize.Height));
            }
            else
            {
                UIElement leftItem = visibleItems[i];
                UIElement rightItem = visibleItems[i + 1];

                double rowHeight = leftItem.DesiredSize.Height > rightItem.DesiredSize.Height ? leftItem.DesiredSize.Height : rightItem.DesiredSize.Height;

                leftItem.Arrange(new Rect(xColumn1, y, columnWidth, rowHeight));
                rightItem.Arrange(new Rect(xColumn2, y, columnWidth, rowHeight));

                y += rowHeight;

                i++;
            }
        }

        return finalSize;
    }
```

I also created my own UserControl for the Items:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label x:Name="captionLabel" Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Caption}"/>
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="inputMask" Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding InputMask, ElementName=userControlBRAIN2AttributePanelItem}" />
</Grid>
```

So I get te following result (from my test application):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRO1S.png)

with collapsed item 3:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkECH.png)

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that no one sugested the use of an [`UniformGrid`](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFUniformGrid.aspx).

All you have to do is declar an `UniformGrid`, set `Columns` to 2 and add your items. Items that are collapsed should have its `Visibility` set to `Collapsed` (duh).

Here's an example:

```
<UniformGrid Columns="2"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center">

    <TextBlock Text="Item 1 " />
    <TextBlock Text="Item 2 " />
    <TextBlock Text="Item 3 " />
    <TextBlock Text="Item 4 " />
</UniformGrid>
```

Will produce the following result:

[image]

And when the `Visibility` of the second `TextBlock` is set to `Collapsed`, here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that solution "appa yip yip", the only point which doesn't work for me here is, that the items have in the UniformGrid no fix height, when multiple items are collapsed, the other items getting a bigger height, because they are always streched to the UniformGrip hieght, doesn't matter how much items are in ...

Answer (score 0):

you can use a ListView that uses a StackPanel or a DockPanel as ItemTemplate.
This is an example (simplified) of what I use to display an observable collection of objects in a list with Grid and DockPannel:

```
                   <ListView x:Name="lbxDroppedDatas" SelectionMode="Single" AllowDrop="True" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" Margin="0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionChanged="lbxDroppedDatas_SelectionChanged" PreviewKeyDown="lbxDroppedDatas_PreviewKeyDown" PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="lbxDroppedDatas_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" >
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=Container}" Height="40" Margin="1" LastChildFill="True">
                                        <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" />
                                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{Binding LineBrush}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0" MouseEnter="Label_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Label_MouseLeave"/>
                                        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="60" MaxLength="14" Text="{Binding CurrentValue, StringFormat=N}" Margin="0,0,33,0" Background="Transparent" Foreground="{Binding LineBrush}" BorderBrush="{Binding LineBrush}" BorderThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsEnabled="False"/>
                                    </DockPanel>
                             </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    </ListView>
```

You could bind the visibility of your list element to a collapsed or visible property.

Answer (score 0):

I'd solve this problem in the following way:

- start with creating a grid with two stack panels (the grid resides within a UserControl or any other placeholder):

  ```
  <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <StackPanel x:Name="LeftPanel" x:FieldModifier="private" Orientation="Vertical" />
      <StackPanel x:Name="RightPanel" x:FieldModifier="private" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" />
  </Grid>
  ```
- to control your items, create a list of items, preferably within the code of your UserControl:
  `private List<FrameworkElement> m_items = new List<FrameworkElement>();`
- for the items you don't want to be visible set the `Visibility` to `Hidden` or `Collapsed`.
- you'd need some method that will select the visible items and place them alternating to the left and right panel. I've came up with some quick method that you need to call each time your list changes (an item is added or removed, visibility of an item is changed):

  ```
  public void SortItems()
  {
      this.LeftPanel.Children.RemoveRange(0, this.LeftPanel.Children.Count);
      this.RightPanel.Children.RemoveRange(0, this.RightPanel.Children.Count);
      this.m_items.Where(i => i.Visibility == Visibility.Visible).ToList().ForEach((i) => { (this.LeftPanel.Children.Count == this.RightPanel.Children.Count ? this.LeftPanel : this.RightPanel).Children.Add(i); } );
  }
  ```

The method simply removes all children of the stack panels and then traverses through the items' list choosing only those which are `Visible` and adds one to the left panel if both panels have the same amount of items in them and to the right panel otherwise.

If you need some other way of selecting into which panel the following item should be added (e.g. `ActualHeight`) simply change the condition that is selecting the panels.

If you want to make this method more elegant you can add some events or dependency properties that will call `SortItems` automatically. Anyway, it's a good start.